# Как работает кэш в браузере? (css стили)

Tags: css, кэширование

Возможно, вопрос достаточно глупый, однако прямого ответа в статьях я не нашел.

Как мы знаем, к сайту (в идеале) подключается один файл css со всеми стилями.

**Однако есть такая ситуация (в вакууме):**

Допустим, на одном домене есть два сайта (какая глупость). Заходим на главную, там две ссылки: сайт1 и сайт2. Структура следующая:

```
/index.html - это наша главная
/site1/index.html - сайт 1
/site1/style.css - стили сайта 1
/site2/index.html - сайт 2
/site2/index.css - стили сайта 2
```

Адреса разные, это очевидно. Мы постоянно работаем только с сайтом 1. Соответственно, в кэше хранятся его css стили. И вдруг мы зашли на сайт 2.

**Что произойдет в кэше?**

1. Стили сайта 2 заменят стили сайта 1 (потому что домен один) ?
2. Стили сайта 2 станут рядом со стилями сайта 1 (потому что адреса разные) ?

**Если ситуация 1, то** как быть, если сайтов не 2, а намного более, и если пихать все в один css, то он будет весить очень и очень много (а нам все стили и не нужны по факту, если мы пользуемся только сайтом 1) ?

**Если ситуация 2, то** выходит, что выгодно подключать те стили, которые актуальны для конкретной страницы, т.к. адреса у каждой страницы свои. Но мы ведь стремимся подключать как можно меньше css-файлов, значит ли это, что возможна только ситуация 1 ?

Поменяется ли результат, если использовать ЧПУ и единую точку входа (насколько я понимаю единую точку входа, адрес всегда один, но страница строится в зависимости от `$_GET` переменных) ?

P.S. Надеюсь, что объяснил вопрос достаточно понятно. Заранее спасибо за ответ(ы).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Будет ситуация **2**

Браузер кэширует файлы по полному url до файла
Например `http://site.com/css/main.css` этот файл будет в кэше

Вторую ситуацию вы написали неверно.
Браузер кэширует стили не для определённой страницы сайта, а по полному url до файла со стилями.

Поэтому существует такая вещь как CDN-хостинг библиотек

Если замечали, в исходниках иногда встречается запись `http://site.com/css/main.css?v4`
Так сбрасывают предыдущий кэш, чтобы сбросить текущий нужно будет написать `http://site.com/css/main.css?v5`

Если настроить nginx с `expires -1` для css, то браузер не закэширует ваш файл со стилями

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то надо делать так: каждому из сайтов свой файл стилей (они станут параллельно), но внутри сайта подключается только один, потому что браузер кэширует "по полному url до файла со стилями", верно?

Comment: Ну если разные сайты используют разные стили, то в index.html каждого сайта прописываете свой файл стилей

Comment: Благодарю. Ответ более чем понятный, спасибо